# How to print or log on function javascript Orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I trying to use print("Hello world") function Orientdb for debugging. 
After click on excute() there is no any result appear.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To see the print you have to open the 'Server.bat' or 'Server.sh' window and you'll see your result.

**Server.bat**

[image]

**Server.sh**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for quickly reply. I connect my orientdb via SSH . and i connect my database by remote:localhost/Demo but still show noting.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using OrientDB standard logger:

```
 com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager.instance().info(this, "This is a log!")
```

Comment: Of course the logger supports all the log levels (debug(), info(), warn(), error())